# Clone a Github repo

Tags: git, github, moodle

I forked a repo from an original-official repo `moodle`. It has over 15 branches having `master` as the branch. I then cloned it on my local machine. Lets say I cloned it in a folder `project` and it created some 50 `folders`.

Doing  `git remote -v` gave the following:

```
origin  https://github.com/ps/moodle.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/ps/moodle.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/moodle/moodle.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/moodle/moodle.git (push)
```

So, I have an `origin` and an `upstream`.

Now, I wanted to `fork` and `clone` another branch from another user. Lets say that branch is `gs`. So, that user maintains this `gs` branch under the same `master` branch from `moodle`. Now, to clone it on my local machine, I created a remote `otheruser` and cloned it.

So, now doing  `git remote -v` gave the following:

```
origin  https://github.com/ps/moodle.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/ps/moodle.git (push)
otheruser   https://github.com/otheruser/moodle.git (fetch)
otheruser   https://github.com/otheruser/moodle.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/moodle/moodle.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/moodle/moodle.git (push)
```

My question is this:

When I cloned the branch `gs`, it created extra sub-directories. So, I mean I'm unable to understand it physically that how will it work? If I do any changes in those extra sub-directories and then push it onto my Github account under the `master` branch, will it be okay?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you index the changes in the sub-directories prior to committing, yes. Nothing is automatically indexed, though.

Answer (score 0):

The `otheruser` is an entirely different git repo. It was forked from the original, but now it's on its own. It can pull and merge in changes from the original but as far as making changes to the original, the best it can do is request that the original [pull in changes](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests) that it made.

You made it unclear as to whether you have direct permission to push to `otheruser`'s fork or not. I'll answer for both cases:

**If you forked:**

When you fork this `otheruser`, you're forking off of that fork. Therefore you are, once again, creating an entirely new repo based on that one, and can at best pull request to change that fork. As far as pushing to your fork, absolutely fine, on any branch you wish, any subdirectories you want; it's yours now.

**If you have direct permission:**

This one's pretty simple, just push onto `otheruser`'s master because you have permission to, as you normally would on your own.